# PhantomJS Node Driver Setting UserAgent

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, user-agent

I am running PhantomJS using the phantom npm module. [Node Phantom Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) However, I cannot figure out how to change the user-agent.

First I tried passing a settings object to page.open like so: `await page.open(url, { userAgent: "spoofed user agent" })` but the user agent is unchanged.

Next I read [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) that settings can be changed by calling the page.setting(key, value) method so I tried: `await page.setting('userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36');` After opening the page.

Neither of these options worked even though it seems like both should work. Does anyone know how to spoof user agent in phantomjs with phantom npm module?

Edit: not sure why but `await page.setting('userAgent', 'userAgent');` is working to change the user agent on the debian box I am using on google cloud compute but not on mac os x.

Comment: Your edit is correct, it should be working. Does the script work at all (except for useragent) on Mac OS or does it fail completely?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to change the property settings of the `page.settings` object  (without the braces)

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();  

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 ...';
```

Found [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) on phantom.js documentation

Comment: PhantomJS is not an npm module, but question is about one, so this answer does not apply unfortunately.